# Sort tableView data from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want that data which come from firebase have to be like in reverse, the last data must be up.

My code to retrieve data:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    isRead = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Child").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        var post = snapshot.value as? String
        if let actualPost = post{
            self.postData.append(actualPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

}
```

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnEws.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
self.postData.append(actualPost)
```

Use

```
self.postData.insert(actualPost,at:0)
```

BTW directly use `if let actualPost = snapshot.value as? String {}`